# I cannot select li elements after i have added it dynamically

Tags: javascript

```
function appendToSelect_pick_loc1(select, value, content,pSize,i) {
  var ulelement=$(select).siblings('.cs-options').children('ul');
  $(ulelement).append("<li data-option=\"\" data-value=\""+value+"\"><span>"+content+"</span></li>");
}
```

The elements are added ,but i cannot select any from them.

Comment: How do you want to select them? There are many ways (assuming select = selecting via selector in jQuery)

Comment: What do you mean select them? SOunds like you are using some script that is generating a menu?

Comment: yes a list is generated dynamically but when i clicked on any element the dropdown didn't closed and no element is selected as if it is disabled

Comment: Impossible to help with the information provided. We need to know the code that is generating the menu/list.

Answer (score 0):

To do operations on a dynamically generated element you do not use the simple `$(selector).click(function(){});` approach.

To select the dynamically created elements you have to use:

```
$(document).on('click',selector,function(){
   //console.log(this); //the selected item
});
```

In place of document you can take any element from the DOM that is static (not generated at runtime) and encloses your selector.